# scroll show but wont work in div inside an absolute div inside a fixed menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, dashboard

Im using sb admin dashboard for my project

[Dashboard1](https://startbootstrap.com/previews/sb-admin-2/)

and right at alert center where i list my alerts, i made the overflow scroll apear but wont work with the whell. works only if you click or drag.

never seen something like it...it is inside an absolute and inside another fixed position

(i realize that in remark dashboard the overflow scroll works great inside the alert)

[Dashboard2](https://getbootstrapadmin.com/remark/base/)

however it may seen activated by a js

thanks for any help in advance...

```
<div class="navbar" style="position:fixed;width:100%;top:0;">
  <li style="position:relative">
    <a href="" class="nav-link">
      icon-for-alert
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-list" style="position:absolute;width:360px">
      <h6 class="dropdown-header">Alerts</h6>
      <div class="dropdown-body" style="height:270px;overflow:auto;">
        <a href="#">
          <span>stuff</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <span>stuff</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <span>stuff</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <span>stuff</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        See All
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>;
```

Comment: Welcome. You're required to post the relevant code here. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please use proper capitalization and punctuation as well, so you're understood clearly.

Answer (score 0):

it was a js conflict from another file. thankyall